# Installation OpenCV 3.0 on Raspberry Pi running Debian Wheezy

Tags: raspbian, opencv

I need some help to find a tutorial or help installing OpenCV-3.0 on my raspberry pi running debian wheezy. The OS was already pre-installed on the micro-sd. I followed some guides online but it seems they are outdated and usually get an error message when running 'make' command at about 56% after several hours of installing. Guide that I followed but didn't work: http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/

---

P.S. I am trying to install OpenCV C++ version

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Interestingly I was able to compile opencv 3.0.0 successfully on my rpi 2 without TBB support. Can you let us know which cmake flags are you using ? It would help us to understand what could be wrong in your case ?

Comment: I followed the guide on the link. `sudo apt-get -y install build-essential cmake cmake-curses-guicmake` @dastaan

Comment: I wasn't able to see the 'make' error again as I succesfully installed version 2.4.9. I am interested to know how you were able to install v3.0 @dastaan

Comment: @saqehi Like I said in my answer, I was having problems (and still having) in compiling 3.0.0 if I use -D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON. When I tried compiling without these flags, it compiled fine.

Comment: Also since it took very long time, I assume that you are compiling it on a Rpi 1 which is a single core arm machine so opencv with TBB support will be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use OpenCV and can compromise with version, you can probably install it from the official Raspbian repository by following apt-get command. This is the easiest way if you don't want to deal with compilation errors and don't want to spend time compiling it on your own which takes about 10 hours on Rpi 1 and 2.5 hours on Rpi 2.

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

This should install all the dependencies along with OpenCV 2.4.1 with Python support.

If you have an Rpi 2 and want to use TBB to gain advantage of multiple cores of Rpi 2, I would advice you to grab the source of 2.4.9 and build it with `-D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON` cmake flags along with other flags as per your requirement. Because libtbb-dev is not available under official Raspbian-wheezy repository.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am installing it the long route right now. I hope I don't get any errors this time around. Otherwise, I will try your approach. If I install with the Python support will still have the C++ full support as well?

Comment: @saqehi Yes. It will have C++ support. :)

Comment: I was able to install the 2.4.9 with no inconvenience. `libtbb` was giving me troubles indeed as it is not available. I compiled and it look a long time as you specified.

Comment: @saqehi If you're compiling it on Rpi 2, you can make use of `make -j4` instead of just `make`. It will run 4 threads while compiling and hence speed up your compilation upto 4 times.

Comment: @saqehi You can mark this as a correct answer if It solved your problem. :)

Comment: @dastaan: Regarding the use of multiple cores on RPi 2  - I got multiple threads working in OpenCV 3.0.0 even with both BUILD_TBB and WITH_TBB set to OFF (=default OpenCV compile settings). I tried to compile with both set to ON too - no difference. The funny thing is only 3 of 4 cores were actually used in both cases (=75% CPU utilization). I tried to set setNumThreads to 4 but it did not help even though this function was able to limit the cores to 1 when set to 1. Would appreciate if anyone knew how to use all 4 cores.

Comment: @Kozuch I didn't get it. Did you try running an actual OpenCV program or just compilation ?

Comment: @dastaan Sorry I did not mention that - I tested real OpenCV performance, not the compilation speed. Namely I tested the StereoBM method - the numbers relate to this method (and most likely to any other methods...).